# SQL Oracle query Constraint

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, check-constraints

BranchNAME should be not null and can have any one of the listed values (Chennai,
Mumbai,Delhi,Bangalore)

I can put single name in check how to put all cities names in check.

```
ALTER TABLE Employee ADD CONSTRAINT Branch CHECK (Branch= 'Delhi');
```

Comment: How would you filter for a list of values in a query's `where` clause? Try doing the same thing, e.g. with `IN (...)`.

Comment: Or OR .. OR .. OR ..

Comment: To make it more flexible you can also create another table with all the values and add a Foreign Key constraint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an `IN` condition:

```
ALTER TABLE Employee ADD CONSTRAINT check_branch_name
    CHECK (Branch IN ('Delhi','Chennai','Mumbai','Bangalore'));
```

and don't forget to add `not null` constraint

```
ALTER TABLE EMPLOYEE MODIFY BRANCH not null;
```

if not exists.